# angular multiple error handlers

Tags: angular, error-handling

In our project we already use a custom error handler using

```
{provide: ErrorHandler, useExisting: CustomErrorHandler}
```

This CustomErrorHandler is provided by third party which logs errors to a central server. In addition to this we want to implement our own central error handling to display errors on screen.

Is there a way to have multiple error handlers in angular?

Comment: Decorate `CustomErrorHandler` with your logic by overriding `CustomErrorHandler`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you @yurzui, for anyone loooking for code here are the snippets that I used:

AppModule.ts:

```
{provider: ErrorHandler, useClass: LocalErrorHandler}
```

LocalErrorHandler.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalErrorHandler extends CustomErrorHandler
{
   handleError(error: any)
   {
       //Local custom handling
       super.handleError(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: But it does not look easy to plug and play like interceptor. Do you have other implement ? @yurzui

Comment: @HungCung what do you mean by not easy to plug and play like interceptor? You just create a class and instead of useExisting, you will write useClass... this IS an interceptor